# passing variable to Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup, get "Unable to get the VLookup Property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm having trouble with the VLookup from Word.

I'm using the statements

```
set wsht = GetObject("I:\Pat's Files\word macro for Julie\Test Excel File.xls").sheets("sheet1")

Period1 = wsht.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("*" & Teacher & "*", wsht.Range("$A$3:$K$5"), 2, 0)
```

If my `Teacher` is `Black,Chris`, I want the value shown in Excel Column 2 to appear in my word macro.

In Excel, the lookup value needs to be `*Black*` or, more precisely `"*" & $A$9 & "*"` where Cell A9 contains the word `Black`.

When I run the macro as above, the system tells me that it is "Unable to get the VLookup Property of the WorksheetFunction class".

If I run the macro with this statement:

```
Period1 = wsht.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("*" & "Black" & "*", wsht.Range("$A$3:$K$5"), 2, 0)
```

I get the value that I need.  Here, I've specifically entered the word "Black" rather than had it in the variable named Teacher.

Something is awry with the way I'm passing the variable name of teacher in the vlookup but I don't know what. How can that vlookup command be written so that a variable name can go in the Vlookup command?

Here is my Code:

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'
'
Dim Teacher As String
Dim objRange
Set wsht = GetObject("I:\Pat's Files\word macro for Julie\Test Excel File.xls").sheets("sheet1")

'Find the teacher's name from the bookmark named Teacher in this Word Document

Dim sMyString As String
Teacher = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Teacher").Range.Text

'Show me the teacher's name it found
MsgBox Teacher

'Lookup the period 1 from Excel
Period1 = wsht.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("*" & Teacher & "*",     wsht.Range("$A$3:$K$5"), 2, 0)

Per1 = Period1

'Put the value of Period 1 in the bookmark named Period1
Set objRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Period1").Range
objRange.Text = Per1
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "Period1", objRange

End Sub
```

Comment: If in Excel the value must be `*Black*`, why are you passing `*Black,Chris*`? The `Unable to get property` means the value cannot be found. Also your second usage example is not different from the first at all, which you might see by putting `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module.

Comment: The difference between my fist and second examples is that in the first, I'm using a variable (that being Teacher) and in the Second I'm specifying that the teachers name is Black (or at least part of his name is Black)

I've tried Option Explicit, it responds with "Invalid Inside Procedure"

Here is my Code:

Comment: `Option Explicit` must be the first line of the entire code module, not the procedure. Your second example is identical to first because it also uses a variable, named `Black`. Apparently you did not declare this variable, and because you have no `Option Explicit`, this goes unnoticed. If you wanted to use the string literal `"Black"`, you'd write `"*" & "Black" & "*"` or simply `"*Black*"`.

Comment: My Mistake, I forgot to put quotes around "black" in my second example...I will go back and set Option Explicit....thanks GSerg

Comment: GSerg, I hope your still there.....I've put Option Explicit as the first line in my macro.  For this little section of code the vLookUp gives me the error.

    Teacher = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Teacher").Range.Text
    MsgBox Teacher
    'Teacher = "Black"
    'MsgBox Teacher
    Period1 = wsht.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("*" &  Teacher & "*", wsht.Range("$A$3:$K$5"), 2, 0)

Comment: I've put Option Explicit as the first line in my macro.  For this little section of code the vLookUp gives me the error.

    Teacher = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Teacher").Range.Text
    MsgBox Teacher
      Period1 = wsht.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("*" &  Teacher & "*", wsht.Range("$A$3:$K$5"), 2, 0)

But for the following, where I've specifically set Teacher = "Black" it works.

    Teacher = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Teacher").Range.Text
     Teacher = "Black"
     Period1 = wsht.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("*" & Teacher & "*", wsht.Range("$A$3:$K$5"), 2, 0)
Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  Somewhere along the line I had and extra character in the bookmark so the Vlookup wasn't getting the correct value to lookup.

A simple error uncovered with help from someone on another forum.

Thanks for your help on this one!

Patrick